# Is there a way to pass an array of generic types so that the generic type of each element is inferred?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, inferred-type

Consider the following:

```
  type ValueMap = {
    foo: 'FOO1' | 'FOO2';
    bar: 'BAR1' | 'BAR2' | 'BAR3';
  };
  type Key = keyof ValueMap;

  type Value<K extends Key> = ValueMap[K];

  type Entry<K extends Key> = {
    key: K;
    value: Value<K>;
  }
```

In other words, an `Entry` consists of a `key` and a `value`, and the set of allowed values depends on the key, so e.g.

```
{key: 'foo', value: 'FOO2'} - valid
{key: 'foo', value: 'BAR3'} - invalid
{key: 'bar', value: 'BAR1'} - valid
{key: 'bar', value: 'FOO2'} - invalid
```

Now, I want to send a set of such entries to a function, and I want the type of each entry to be inferred from *that element's key*. However, If I do this as an array, this doesn't work very well:

```
  function sendArray<K extends Key>(v: Array<Entry<K>>) {
    ...
  }

  sendArray([{key: 'foo', value: 'FOO2'}, {key: 'bar', value: 'BAR1'}])
  sendArray([{key: 'foo', value: 'FOO2'}, {key: 'bar', value: 'FOO1'}]) // compiles :(
```

Here, `sendArray` is called with `K` being inferred to `"foo" | "bar"`, and each array element is validated only so that `key` is assignable to `"foo" | "bar"` and `value` is assignable to `ValueMap<"foo" | "bar">`, i.e., values from `foo` are valid for `bar` entries, and vice versa. :(

I know that if I use a record type instead, it works:

```
  type Entries<K extends Key> = {
    [P in K]?: Value<P>;
  }

  function sendRecord<K extends Key>(v: EntryRecord<K>) {
  }

  sendRecord({foo: 'FOO2', bar: 'BAR3'})
  sendRecord({foo: 'FOO2', bar: 'FOO1'}) // does not compile! :)
```

... which is nice, but I'd really want this to work for an array. Is there some way to do this, so that the first array element in inferred to be a `Entry<"foo">` and the second element is inferred to be a `Entry<"bar">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need generics here at all, but if for some reason you still need them outside of this exact issue we will still have to make `Entry` nongeneric. The desired type is:

```
{
    key: "foo";
    value: "FOO1" | "FOO2";
} | {
    key: "bar";
    value: "BAR1" | "BAR2" | "BAR3";
}
```

To achieve this we will use the [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type Entry = {
  [K in Key]: {
    key: K;
    value: ValueMap[K];
  };
}[Key];
```

Then, in the `sendArray` we have to modify the generic to accept the `Entry[]`, not `Key`. And to make sure that read-only arrays are also accepted we will add `readonly` to the constraint:

```
function sendArray<E extends readonly Entry[]>(v: E) {}
```

Testing:

```
sendArray([
  { key: "foo", value: "FOO2" },
  { key: "bar", value: "BAR1" },
]);
sendArray([
  { key: "foo", value: "FOO2" },
  { key: "bar", value: "FOO1" },
]); // doesn't compile :)
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QLJzFAvFA3gKCigDMB7UgLigCIAxAeXoEZqoAfGh+gJmoG5CUAEZwATlWoAhAIIAlFuxozZvRVLkBmfvgC+A0JCgBpCCGxQA1qdLFYiFOjAD8B6PGQQAPEagQAHsAQAHYAJgDOxqYAfObuDhgA2kYAus6uUACiQcCiZjgERElQAJZBkSDJVAVElqZURgI1UABu9hBUcWiJKY1QerpJpqn4+MRIQQDGwMWkZWHBIdKionAgnhm+AQsRohBwIbMIZlk5IAnJUQAUzVQZAJR4OiPzoUsrIJcJgri1IBJkpGoABoWm0JFxVDogd9fhIRKJgaCPBJlAoofhkncBC9FstVp8YVY-jQAYjWsjOIxIdCiD8iXCxGSwZTmKx0Zi+FAAPRcqAHCBhIIAcmAUAmpAAtmBighoBQ7vggA)

Comment: This seems to be the best solution! I had a feeling mapped types would be involved somehow, but couldn't figure it out completely. Thanks! I've verified that this fulfills my requirements. And yes, I do need generics for other reasons not obvious to the dumbed-down question.

Answer (score 0):

As every `Entry` object in the array argument must be type checked individually you'll need a constraint that does just that. In the following example I used an additional generic `createEntry` function which ensures that no mismatching `key`s and `value`s can used in the same object. So you basically type-check each entry separately.

```
type ValueMap = {
  foo: "FOO1" | "FOO2";
  bar: "BAR1" | "BAR2" | "BAR3";
};
type Key = keyof ValueMap;

type Value<K extends Key> = ValueMap[K];

type Entry<K extends Key> = {
  key: K;
  value: Value<K>;
};

function createEntry<K extends Key>(key: K, value: Value<K>): Entry<K> {
  return { key, value };
}
declare function sendArray<K extends Key>(v: Entry<K>[]): void;

sendArray([createEntry('foo', 'FOO1'), createEntry('bar', 'BAR1')]);
sendArray([createEntry('foo', 'BAR1'), createEntry('bar', "FOO1")]);
//                            ~~~~~~                      ~~~~~~
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QLJzFAvFA3gWACgooAzAe3IC4oAiAMQHlGBGWqAHzqcYCZaA3ERIAjOACcatAEIBBAEptOdOfP7KZCgMyCiAXyGFQkKAGkIIbFADWF8qViIU6MIaLHo8ZBAA8pqBAAHsAQAHYAJgDOZhYAfFZezhgA2qYAum5G4NAAoqHA4iB%20AcFhUTEg8TgExDYWNKaGJABuThA0ib6msYYGRESkSKEAxsAAluShUMPiEHAheQVF-kEhEdHmlQAUtiANADRQrd4dbX6xAJQ0i4XneMJQs8BI4lO4dSCHxyhQfYR6RHCEGGCAk0EGI3GkygkTKsnE4jgyxKa3Km1iW2a13yt26yTSVyO5DG4UysIi8MRIC2yRmcwWOOpAHIKOQmYcmTwWEyLoc6fMIDdmWJxOyoEzVNyLgTDOTwpSkTT%20QyllsWZQxRKFFK%20bMBUK1SKxQxmGxpRdDAB6S0kW12%200Ox1QAB%20rrdTo99rdbqAA)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually had something like this in mind, but thought it was too clunky to require a factory function for each object, but in other situations it might be the best way. Thanks!